# How do I debug port 445 being filtered on one interface only

Tags: networking, kali-linux

I'm trying to figure out why my port 445 is being FILTERED on ppp0, an openfortivpn VPN.

I first found this problem when trying to run impacket's smbserver, and found that while `smbclient -L 127.0.0.1` worked, net view or `smbclient -L 172.xxx.xxx.xxx` did **not** work from another computer across the VPN.

I also tried setting up an ncat listener on port 445, and found that I could connect to it from localhost: `ncat 127.0.0.1 445`, as well as from my main computer: `ncat 192.168.xxx.xxx 445`, but again, not from the VPN network.

I also tried nmap scanning. From localhost or from my main computer, the port is listed as **open**. From across the VPN it is listed as **filtered**.

I can't figure out why it would be filtered.

(everything as root)

```
iptables -L -n
```

shows everything open

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-before-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-reject-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-track-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

etc.

and ss shows ncat listening on all ip's

```
ss -tulpn | grep :445
tcp   LISTEN  0       10                   0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:*      users:(("ncat",pid=25283,fd=4))                                                
tcp   LISTEN  0       10                      [::]:445               [::]:*      users:(("ncat",pid=25283,fd=3))
```

How do I debug this further?

---

I should also mention that I have tried running the smbserver on port 444, and then it works fine. Only, so far as I understand, Windows cannot read an smbshare on a port other than 445

Comment: Looking into your issue it appears that port 445 is in fact the smb port and Windows will not use smb on any other port. Your network provider has likely blocked this due to the fact that having smb open to internet leaves people open to the massive amounts of vulnerabilities in smb. Remember wannacry? Contact their support to confirm that they are in fact blocking it.

Comment: You are correct that windows won't use SMB on any other port, as I mentioned at the end of my q.
I don't think it's the network provider, however, as it's going through a VPN, which means all internet traffic is going through the VPN port anyway, and getting translated on the other side. If anything, it's probably the VPN filtering it.

Comment: Your VPN if provided by a third-party would qualify as a network provider. If their configurations force all of your traffic through a specific port on their network for whatever reason that would most certainly prevent smb from working properly. I would still reach out to their support to confirm their configurations and/or consult with them about how to use smb on their network.